# How to dewrap 360 fov camera footage?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using gscam package to publish the footage of Insta360 cam.So is there any process to dewrap the fish view of the camera footage and republish it in two seperate topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301970/how-to-dewrap-360-fov-camera-footage?/) by [Katta Nigam](https://answers.ros.org/users/37044/katta-nigam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-29**:
The question is dewarp them to what? Both of the fisheye images have a FOV just over 180 degrees. Rectifying such images will necessarily crop off some of the images. What are you planning on using the dewarped images for? Would a skybox be more suitable?

**Comment by [Katta Nigam](https://answers.ros.org/users/37044/katta-nigam/) on 2018-08-29**:
I want to detect qr codes.So for that the image view should be straight i.e undistorted so for that I thought of dewraping the image and then use the footage for qr detection. So is there any way to do that qr detection. Is there any package to Detect qr or dewraping and republish the footage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe #q277153 has some useful information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0